# How to define a vector3 in unity3d using unityscript

Tags: vector, unity-game-engine, unityscript

i am trying to define a vector3 in my unityscript.

I've already tried writing this:

```
cubeVector = vector(1,2,1)
```

Thank you,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In unity3D you can declare a Vector3 like this:

```
var myVector = Vector3(1,2,1);
```

Your code has the following faults:

- You didn't write var before cubeVector
- You didn't end your line with ;

Try also visiting the following [page](http://docs.unity3d.com/412/Documentation/ScriptReference/index.Vectors.html).